# Пропадает подсветка иконки дропдауна при наведении курсором на подменю

Tags: css, svg, меню

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы стрелка дроп дауна оставалась подсвеченной, когда открывается подменю?

Сейчас она подсвечивается, только когда наводишь непосредственно на основной пункт меню. Но стоит спуститься мышкой вниз в подменю, подсветка исчезает.

[image: изображение]

```css
.menu-item-has-children>a::after {
  content: '';
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 24 24' width='16' height='16'%3E%3Cpath fill='none' d='M0 0h24v24H0z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M12 13.172l4.95-4.95 1.414 1.414L12 16 5.636 9.636 7.05 8.222z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E);
  position: absolute;
  right: 18px;
  top: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}

.menu-item-has-children>a:hover::after {
  filter: invert(81%) sepia(6%) saturate(1976%) hue-rotate(89deg) brightness(83%) contrast(86%);
}
```

```html
<nav id="navigation" class="primary-navigation mobile-menu-wrapper" role="navigation">
  <ul id="menu-1" class="menu clearfix toggle-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-1" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1 toggle-menu-item-parent">
      <a title="Статьи по психологии" href="">Статьи</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu toggle-submenu" style="display: none;">
        <li id="menu-item-49" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-49"><a href="">Как и где найти хорошего психолога</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-50" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-50"><a href="">Виды психотерапии</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-38" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-38"><a href="">Ловушки мышления</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-52"><a href="">Сон и сны</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Так у вас стиль задан только для селектора `.menu-item-has-children > a::after`, как только мышка уходит с этого пункта, пропадает и подсветка. Нужно через запятую добавить второй селектор, что-то вроде `.menu-item-has-children > a::after, .menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li:hover`

Comment: @Quazimorda
Предложенный код не сработал. Когда курсор на области li ("Статьи"), то иконка светится. Поэтому я думал, что нужно прописать условия для области с подменю. Вроде такого 

.sub-menu .toggle-submenu:hover .menu-item-has-children > a::after {filter: invert(81%) sepia(6%) saturate(1976%) hue-rotate(89deg) brightness(83%) contrast(86%);}
Но оно тоже не работает

Comment: при переносе вашего кода в снипет он не работает и я проверить своё предложение не смог. Потому и написал коммент, а не ответ. Даже стрелка drop down не отображается.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
.menu-item-has-children:hover > a::after {
    filter: invert(81%) sepia(6%) saturate(1976%) hue-rotate(89deg) brightness(83%) contrast(86%);
}
```

То есть у вас hover прикреплен к первому тегу **a** элемента с классом **.menu-item-has-children** В моем случает - при наведении на элемент с классом .menu-item-has-children взять первый элемент **a** и применить такие то стили к его псевдоэлементу.

Но это все чисто логически, проверять надо))